# Combining AWS ECR lifecycle rules using "and"

Tags: amazon-ecr

I would like to set up an AWS ECR lifecycle policy such that an image is expired iff it is older than 90 days **and** there are at least 10 more recent images.  In other words, I want to keep all images that are newer than 90 days, and I want to keep at least the newest 10 images regardless of how old they are.

If I am reading the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/LifecyclePolicies.html) correctly, this is not possible:

> An image is expired by exactly one or zero rules.

and a single rule cannot specify both `sinceImagePushed` and `imageCountMoreThan`.

Is this correct?  Is there any workaround?